# Finding a functional derivative

Tags: functions

I'm a bit stuck on finding the derivative of a functional $H[f]=\int g[f(x)]dx$. I've started off with $$\frac{\delta H[f]}{\delta f(x_0)}=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \frac{1}{\epsilon}\bigg[\int g[f(x)+\epsilon\delta (x-x_0)]dx-\int g[f(x)] dx\bigg]$$ I think that I should probably put it into some form similar to $$\frac{\delta H[f]}{\delta f(x_0)}=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \frac{1}{\epsilon}\bigg[\int g[f(x)]+[\epsilon\delta (x-x_0)]*\mathrm{something}\ dx-\int g[f(x)] dx\bigg]$$ so that the $\int g[f(x)]dx$ parts cancel out leaving it as $$\frac{\delta H[f]}{\delta f(x_0)}=\int \delta (x-x_0)]*\mathrm{something}\ dx$$however I have no idea how to get whatever "something" should be. (Possibly some part of functions I've forgotten), thanks.

Comment: Is $g$ an ordinary function or some kind of functional?

Comment: @md2perpe An ordinary function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to use a mathematically better definition than the physicist definition you are using:
$$
\left< \frac{\delta H[f]}{\delta f(x)}, \phi(x) \right>
= \left. \frac{d}{d\lambda} H[f+\lambda\phi] \right|_{\lambda=0}
$$
where $\phi$ is a "test function".

By the chain rule we have
$$\begin{align}
\frac{d}{d\lambda} H[f+\lambda\phi]
& = \frac{d}{d\lambda} \int g[f(x)+\lambda\phi(x)] \, dx \\
& = \int \frac{d}{d\lambda} g[f(x)+\lambda\phi(x)] \, dx \\
& = \int g'[f(x)+\lambda\phi(x)] \, \phi(x) \, dx \\
\end{align}$$
so
$$
\left< \frac{\delta H[f]}{\delta f(x)}, \phi(x) \right>
= \left. \int g'[f(x)+\lambda\phi(x)] \, \phi(x) \, dx \right|_{\lambda=0}
= \int g'[f(x)] \, \phi(x) \, dx
= \left< g'[f(x)], \phi(x) \right>
$$

Thus,
$$
\frac{\delta H[f]}{\delta f(x)}
= g'[f(x)]
$$

Comment: Awesome thanks a bunch! (I’ll accept when time limit has run out)

Comment: Apologise for asking this later on - what do the $\langle\rangle$ mean? At first I thought it was the product but now I'm doubting (I feel a bit silly for asking this oops)..

Comment: $\langle u, \phi \rangle$ is a way to write the application of a linear functional $u$ on a function $\phi$. It's especially common in the theory of distributions. It's not a coincidence that it looks like an inner product, as it is an inner product if $u$ and $\phi$ are realvalued functions.